# Eclipse quick dialog DefaultInformationControl

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Those who work with eclipse must be familiar with the quick dialogs  eclipse provides like quick access( CTRL + 3) Quick outline (CTRL+O) quick type hierarchy(CTRL+T) etc.
Is there a way we can make our own dialog like that in our eclipse plugin.

Any idea how to do it? some resource related to the topic will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think that you refer to plugin development http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Plug-in_Development_FAQ

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing specific eclipse is doing there. You need to define keybindings for the command you have defined. Please go through the link : [Key Bindings](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCommandsKeybindings/article.html) for more information.

Comment: Actually I want to know how to make that yellow box, I know how to do the key bindings and stuff.

Comment: @ shiyamhoda: Sorry for the confusion. Please have a look at it http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/145687/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. At least now i know whats its called.